# Convert iteration number to a limited range (like day of week number)

Tags: php, range, limit

I need to translate a iteration number to a range of between 1 and 7.

```
$y = keepInRange(1, 7, $i)
```

The result input -> output is expected as follow

- 1 -> 1
- ...
- 7 -> 7
- 8 -> 1
- 9 -> 2
- ...
- 14 -> 7
- 15 -> 1

I already tried the following without success:

```
min(7, max(1, $numberToStr[$i])) (all output 1)
$y = $i % 7 (all outputs 0, Edit: this was a mistake by me, its the solution when +1 is added.)
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: sure, it needs to stay between 1 and 7, if it gets above it need to get lowered by each 7 possible. 
for an example: 23 you can remove 7 three times. which remains 2.

Comment: Yes, should the output be an array? (variable $y) What is $i ?

Comment: That expression should work: `($i - 1) % 7 + 1` . You need $i to be an integer and not a string.

Comment: what about if curr number (`$i`) is negative? what should be the output?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, thanks that worked, and made me realize i made a mistake)

Comment: @mitkosoft doesn't happen, its an iteration. so you always start with 1 (0, +1 manual added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$num = 15;
$res= $num%7;
if($res == 0)
{
    echo "7";
}
else
{
    echo $res;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/dDGs3

i hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$day_of_week = $num <= 7 ? $num : $num % 7;
```

Demo:

```
for($num=1; $num<25; $num++) {
    $day_of_week = $num <= 7 ? $num : $num % 7;
    echo '<p>'.$num.': '.$day_of_week.'</p>';
}
```

[Demo in JS](https://jsfiddle.net/ew4nuxsq/).